# Grouped Bar chart in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to make a grouped bar chart in seaborn with the following data. How do I do this? The seaborn documentation has a "hue" parameter but how can I use this with multiple columns I want to display?

```
Type        Single Double Many
McDonalds        1      2   10
BK               4      8    7
Popeyes         11      4   11
```

Heres an example of what I've done this using matplotlib...want to do this in seaborn though

```
df.plot.bar(figsize = (20,10), xlabel = 'Type', ylabel = 'Counts', title = 'Type Counts', rot = 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you convert the data to vertical format and set the original column name to hue, you will get a graph that is grouped by type.

```
df.set_index('Type', inplace=True)
df = df.stack().to_frame('value').reset_index()
df.rename(columns={'level_1':'Item'},inplace=True)

df.head()

         Type     Item  value
0   McDonalds   Single      1
1   McDonalds   Double      2
2   McDonalds     Many     10
3          BK   Single      4
4          BK   Double      8

import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(data=df, x='Type', y='value', hue='Item')
```

[image]